# Java 8 streams - how to filter a list and get a value

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Lets say I have Animal object and successors. 
One of them is Dog and only he implements

```
public interface Barkable{
    Bark getBark();
}
```

Now, I have

```
List<Animal> animals
```

Which holds all animal types and I want to collect all instances of Bark
(which only exists in Dog).
I can do it Java 7 style

```
 ArrayList<Bark> barks = new ArrayList<>();
 for (Animal animal : AnimalsList) {
     if (animal instanceof Barkable){
         barks.add((Barkablle) dog).getBark();
     }
}
```

How do I do it in Java 8 streams?
Will it be as fast as the java-8 version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `filter()` to get the `Barkable` instances and then use `map` to get the `Bark`s :

```
List<Bark> barks = AnimalsList.stream()
                              .filter (a -> a instanceof Barkable) 
                              .map (a -> ((Barkable) a).getBark())
                              .collect (Collectors.toList());
```

As for the running time, you'll have to test for yourself. It will depend on the size of the input list, and you may be able to make it run faster by using `parallelStream()` instead of `stream()` (if your input is large enough for a parallel stream to make a difference).

Comment: If you use parallelStream() the solution will actually be faster for Collections of more than 10k elements. In contrast to the for loop a parallelStream can run on all your cores and the Collector will concurrently collect all the Barkables.

Comment: @Christoph Grimmer-Dietrich: even the single-threaded use of the stream API can run faster than the `for` loop, especially for >10k elements. Not only can the underlying `Spliterator` access the source `ArrayList`’s backing array directly, the `Collector` is free to choose whatever `List` implementation is feasible for collecting, i.e. the `ArrayList` used in the `for` loop has to copy all elements when raising the capacity while the `Collector` may return a non-`public` `List` implementation not suffering from that issue.